# Export SwiftUI View via UnsafeMutableRawPointer

Tags: swift, pointers, swiftui, ffi, unsafemutablepointer

I'd like to return a SwiftUI `Text` View as an `UnsafeMutableRawPointer`, abiding by the C calling convention, so another language can FFI into it for use.

```swift
@_cdecl("hi")
func hi (txt: UnsafeMutablePointer<CChar>) -> () {
   var view = ViewBuilder.buildBlock(Text(String(cString: txt)))
   return UnsafeMutableRawPointer(Unmanaged.passUnretained(view).toOpaque())
}
```

But I am receiving the following error:

```
Cannot invoke 'passUnretained' with an argument list of type '(Text)'
```

How can get at the underlying pointer of a SwiftUI `Text` object ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap it by your own class

```
@_cdecl("hi")
func hi (txt: UnsafeMutablePointer<CChar>) -> UnsafeMutableRawPointer {
   let view = ViewBuilder.buildBlock(Text(String(cString: txt)))
    return UnsafeMutableRawPointer(Unmanaged.passUnretained(Wrapper(text: view)).toOpaque())
}

final class Wrapper {
    let text: Text
    init(text: Text) {
        self.text = text
    }
}
```